# Django Ajax Request Not Executing Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to send an ajax request to a view called getToken(). I'm not sure why it isn't working. The console outputs "0: ". If I include the code inside my home view which is the page the call is being made from it will change the page to the json output and not the documentid I told it too. It doesn't call getToken at all even though its set up in the urls file to and my ajax url is set to that url.

When a user clicks the create token on his profile it will send a ajax request to getToken and return that output on the page in the output . Thus, the user can then give that key to his friends so they can add him or email or text the key.

HTML

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <script {% static "ChompMe/jquery.js" %}></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#create_token").click(function() {
                    var csrf = '{{ csrf_token }}';
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST' ,
                        url: '/gettoken',
                        datatype: 'json' ,
                        async: true,
                        data:{
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                            create_token: 'create_token',
                        },
                        success: function(json) {
                            console.log(csrf);
                            console.log(json.message);
                            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (json.message);

                        },
                        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Token:" + " Request Failed.";
                            }                       
                      });

            });
        });
    </script>
        <title>ChompMe
        {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

        <form method='POST' >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button id='create_token' name = 'create_token' value='create_token' > Create Token </button>
        </form>
        <p id='output'>
        Token:
        </p>
    </body>
</html>

Urls.py

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', logout_page),
        url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'), # If user is not login it will redirect to login page
        url(r'^register/$', register),
        url(r'^home$', home),
        url(r'^register/success/$', register_success),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^gettoken$', getToken),
        url(r'^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+$', friends),
    )

Views.Py

    @login_required
    @csrf_protect
    def getToken(request):
        print 'getToken'
        post_data = request.POST.copy()
        username = request.user

        if request.POST.has_key('create_token'):
            datetimes = datetime.now()
            enc_token = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(request.user) + str(datetimes))
            token = enc_token
            context = {'token':token}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context),content_type="application/json")   

    @login_required
    @csrf_protect
    def home(request):
        print 'home'
        post_data = request.POST.copy()
        username = request.user

        if request.POST.has_key('create_token'):
            datetimes = datetime.now()
            enc_token = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(request.user) + str(datetimes))
            token = enc_token
            context = {'token':token}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context),content_type="application/json")       

        user_data = UserProfile.objects.filter(username=str(request.user))
        print user_data
        context = {'user': request.user,
                       'user_data':user_data,
                    }

        return render_to_response('home.html',context ,  RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `/gettoken` to `/gettoken/`.